# vuetify : no documentation for v-data-table-header component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

Does anyone know how to exactly use `<v-data-table-header>` in vuetify? 
In v-data-table, there seems to be api documentation for `v-data-footer` and `v-edit-dialog` but I can't find anything on `v-data-table-header`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for the `v-data-table-header` can be found be using the component search here..

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/api-explorer/

You'll also see that the `mobile` prop can be controlled via `header-props` in the [data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#data-tables)

Comment: In the short time since you've posted this answer, the link now returns a 404...