# Vuetify custom data table header sorting

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my Vue project, I'm using the Vuetify `v-data-table`. I use a custom header like so (simplified):

```
<template v-slot:header="{ props, on }">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.value">
      <v-simple-checkbox
        v-if="header.value === 'data-table-select'"
        v-model="props.everyItem"
        :indeterminate="props.someItems && !props.everyItem"
        color="purple"
        @input="on['toggle-select-all']"
      ></v-simple-checkbox>
      <span v-else>{{ header.text }}</span>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</template>
```

The custom header, works but without sorting. How can I add sorting capabilities? I have been searching, but can't seem to find an

Comment: please add a minimum working example with your v-data-table. Normally you make a v-data-table and use the v-slot:header.name, in your case v-slot:header.data-table-select to modify a single header. otherwise i suggest you use the v-data-table-header component

Comment: I saw the v-data-table-header component API, but I'm not sure how to use it. There doesn't seem to be an example for it. It is also mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969833/vuetify-no-documentation-for-v-data-table-header-component), but without a clear solution.

Comment: Hey @reynard80 - did you find a solution to this?  I have the same query here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70975751/how-to-trigger-sort-function-in-custom-v-data-table-column-headers

Comment: No, I haven't.. Requirements for the project changed and a custom header wasn't required anymore..